# WampServer: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, wampserver

I am using Wamp Server for my project development. When I installed it to my system and tried to open a default project **my-site**, it is showing error as **The requested URL /my-site/** was not found on this server.

I checked, mod_rewrite is enabled.

Does anyone have a slight idea of how to get rid of this?

All positive suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try localhost/my-site/

Comment: @Aphire tried that, still not working

Comment: are you able to see default wampserver page on localhost?

Comment: @Izzatz Yes I can see that, but when I hover over the link to project **my-site**, it doesn't show localhost or 127.0.0.1 before the project name.

Comment: It changed **$suppress_localhost = false;**, it started working. For more details, please refer: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server**

Comment: Virtual Hosts are the recommended solution. When you come to move your code to a live host, there are less issues when you create a Virtual Host to run your development in that looks exactly like the eventual live environment